# Dialogflow: when to use response.json() vs DialogflowApp

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I started writing a dialogflow fulfillment extending https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation. They don't use DialogflowApp and just call response.json().

However, I also found https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/DialogflowApp where fulfillment is done with the DialogflowApp.

When do you use each? and why does the Dialogflow Key Concepts and Basic Fulfillment document not mention to DialogflowApp at all?

The first route (sending response directly) doesn't seem to have a way to deal with permissions and push/daily notifications, while DialogflowApp does.

Will the documentation for sending responses directly be extended to handle permissions? What is the best practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Actions on Google](http://actions.google.com), go with the [Actions on Google client library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/) and `DialogflowApp`. This only supports Actions on Google.

If you are using other integrations that work with Dialogflow, such as Slack, then you should use the fulfillment library and documentation provided by Dialogflow.

Comment: Hi Nick, My question is why I should use Actions on Google vs Dialogflow. Is this purely based on the other integrations supported by Dialgoflow (such as Slack)? What features do Actions on Google have that is not in Dialogflow? Is there a plan to merge these two products into the same roadmap?

Comment: Actions on Google is for the Google Assistant. There are some features that are only supported through Assistant, like permissions and notifications. If you are looking for a broader set of integrations, you may not be able to use certain features. If Slack doesn't support a particular feature, it isn't something that can be merged into Dialogflow directly.